# WPF Spell Checker Ignore words with numbers

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, spell-checking

I'm using the built in WPF spell checker and it works pretty well. However it would be nice to have an option for 'Ignore words that contain numbers' like Word has for things like A100, etc.  Is this possible with the WPF spell checker?  I have googled and played with it and haven't found anything so I'm thinking not, but wanted to ask.  If not is there a recommended way to implement this?

Comment: What built in spell checker?

Comment: WPF allows build in checking.  I put Language="en-US" in the control declaration, then in a textbox put SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True".  It will use the built in dictionary for the selected language and you can add custom dictionaries in the code behind...  Pretty cool but missing some options like this as far as I can tell

Comment: OK then it is the TextBox spellcheck.

Comment: I guess so yes.  So any way to change the behavior that you are aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to .NET 4.6.1 on Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 and try it again. WPF has an updated implementation of spell-checker on these platforms that would ignore words containing numbers.

On Windows 7, and Windows 8 (and Vista SP2), WPF uses an older OS facility for spell-checking whose default behavior is what you see (i.e. A100 would likely be marked as being mis-spelled).

Unless you can enumerate the full set of words containing digits that you would like to exclude from being marked as misspelled, you really don't have a workaround on Win 7 & Win 8. If you can enumerate them (which is admittedly unlikely), then you can supply the list as a custom dictionary to WPF, which will cause those words to be ignored.

Comment: Unfortunately my app is an add-on to another program so I'm stuck on.net 4.5 for now...

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you retarget your application to a newer framework version. You can continue running an application targeted for 4.5 on a 4.6.1 runtime - which is what I suggested you try out.

Comment: Ok I guess I'll try that.  It's commercial software though, so I guarantee that every customer is using .NET 4.6.1...